# How to create dynamic Name value for Magento?

Tags: magento

I could add a bunch of code to app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/catalog/product/list.phtml, but I was wondering if there was a way I could create the "Name" value in another file and retrieve it concisely in the aforementioned file.

Instead of hard-coding a name for every item, I would like to cobble together the name from each product's attributes, and use different logic depending on product type.

Semi Pseudo code:

```
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
// universal attributes:
$manuf = $attributes['manufacturer']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
$color = $attributes['color']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
$type = $attributes['product_type']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

// base name, added to below
$name = $manuf . ' ' . $type . ' in ' . $color;

// then logic for specific types
switch($type) {
  case 'baseball hat':
    $team = $attributes['team']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    $name .= ' for ' . $team;
  break;
  case 'stilts':
    $length = $attributes['length']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    $name .= ' - ' . $length . ' feet long';
  break;
}
```

As this logic could get pretty long, I feel like it shouldn't all be crammed into list.phtml. But how should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom block class. But it's easier to create helper method for name generation.
More information about helpers:

- http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-helper-howto-tutorial-113
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento#6
- http://pravams.com/2011/06/10/magento-call-helper-files-in-template-block-models/

Comment: That sounds better. I just need a place to store and retrieve the logic. If you have a link to information or a tutorial on the subject it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of code should be put inside the product model. The nicest way would be to [override the product class](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/266479/#t360775), but for simplicity i'll describe the easier method:

1) Copy

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
```

to

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php
```

2) Add a new method to the file

```
/**
 * Get custom name here...
 *
 * @return    string
 */
public function getCombinedName()
{
    // your code below....
    $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
    // universal attributes:
    $manuf = $attributes['manufacturer']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    $color = $attributes['color']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    $type = $attributes['product_type']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

    // base name, added to below
    $name = $manuf . ' ' . $type . ' in ' . $color;

    // then logic for specific types
    switch($type) {
        case 'baseball hat':
            $team = $attributes['team']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            $name .= ' for ' . $team;
      break;
      case 'stilts':
        $length = $attributes['length']->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        $name .= ' - ' . $length . ' feet long';
      break;

    }

    return $name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks awesome. Related question, though. I have an attribute called 'model' (i.e. the model number, different than the sku). For some reason I cannot retrieve 'model' using the above code. I'm thinking I may have used a reserved word or something. Also, sku could not be retrieved (probably need different method).

Comment: using Model as a name could well cause an issue but I am not sure off the top of my head, you can always get attributes using this method:
$_product->getData('attribute_code');
Although if the attribute is type dropdown you should use: $_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code');